# How can I restore or load backup rdb file in in-memory redis?

Tags: kubernetes, redis, redis-cluster

I have Redis instances in k8s with one master and 2 slave. I backup from rdb file that said for persistent Redis but I don't have persistent path so when I copy backup rdb file to data path of Redis then I should restart. Because i don't persist my data path, data will be lost after restart.

What should I do to restore successfully in in-memory Redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis doesn't support loading an RDB file at runtime, only at startup.
there are some external tools that can translate the rdb file to RESTORE commands, like redis-rdb-cli, etc. but maybe you should just find a way to place the file on the pod before Redis starts.